# How to create a function to center windows

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm using the jqgrid, and to focus the popup to add, delete and edit, I need to use the parameter `beforeShowForm` that before this show window, shows the center of the screen. The problem is I have to always do the same code for these three functions.

The function is as follows:

```
{ // edit option
  beforeShowForm: function(form) {
    var dlgDiv = $("#editmod" + $(this)[0].id);
    var parentDiv = dlgDiv.parent();
    var dlgWidth = dlgDiv.width();
    var parentWidth = parentDiv.width();
    var dlgHeight = dlgDiv.height();
    var parentHeight = parentDiv.height();
    var parentTop = parentDiv.offset().top;
    var parentLeft = parentDiv.offset().left;
    dlgDiv[0].style.top =  Math.round(parentTop / 2) + "px";
    dlgDiv[0].style.left = Math.round(parentLeft + (parentWidth-dlgWidth  )/2 )  + "px";
  }
},
```

In order to reuse the same code, I would create a separate function to be always writing the same amount of code. I tried to create the following function:

Function:

```
function test(dlgDiv)
{
  var parentDiv = dlgDiv.parent();
  var dlgWidth = dlgDiv.width();
  var parentWidth = parentDiv.width();
  var dlgHeight = dlgDiv.height();
  var parentHeight = parentDiv.height();
  var parentTop = parentDiv.offset().top;
  var parentLeft = parentDiv.offset().left;
  dlgDiv[0].style.top =  Math.round(parentTop / 2) + "px";
  dlgDiv[0].style.left = Math.round(parentLeft + (parentWidth-dlgWidth  )/2 )  + "px";
}
```

In Grid:

```
{ // edit option
  beforeShowForm: function(form) {
    var dlgDiv = $("#editmod" + $(this)[0].id);
    test(dlgDiv);
  }
},
```

But continued without giving. Says that the value dlgDiv is not defined. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What is this horror? `$(this)[0].id`? Why not just use `this.id`???

Comment: Maybe if you gave us the full error message, or at least which line is throwing it.

Comment: @Kolink because i call first parameter of grid ;)

Comment: @gdoron I'll edit to understand better

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the selector you use here:

```
var dlgDiv = $("#editmod" + $(this)[0].id);
```

Whatever element you're trying to get isn't being returned, because the selector can't find it. You should revise your selector to reflect the ID of the element you're attempting to find.

If you've done that and you still have an issue, the problem lies with your context and `this` doesn't mean what you think it means in the above line of code. You'll have to show us more code before I can elaborate on that, though.